# Install an exe via bat file if directory doesn't exist

Tags: batch-file, installation, exe, gpo

I'm calling a bat file from a windows startup script in a GPO and think I may have an error in my syntax, any ideas? The intention is to install the GoToManage unattended access program, but only if it isn't already installed.

```
@echo off
if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\GoToAssist Express Customer" (
    exit
) ELSE (
if EXIST "C:\Program Files\Citrix\GoToAssist Express Customer" (
    exit
) ELSE (
    start \\serv1\SoftwareDeploy\RemoteSupport\RemoteSupport.exe
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\GoToAssist Express Customer" GOTO End
if EXIST "C:\Program Files\Citrix\GoToAssist Express Customer" GOTO End

start \\serv1\SoftwareDeploy\RemoteSupport\RemoteSupport.exe

:End
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, that works perfectly - thanks. With fresh eyes this morning I noticed that I'm missing a parenthesis `)` from the end of my code, whilst I haven't tested it perhaps my original solution would be correct after rectifying this error?

Comment: @user1284559 - Maybe.  Give it a try and see.  I've never really done batch files in that style.